# How to use CellMeasurer in react-virtualized Table?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I use react-virtualized Table to render a table with many rows. I don't want my long text to be trimmed due to the fixed column width, so I want to use CellMeasurer to measure the width dynamically.

This is an example using Grid. It works fine.

```
render() {
  const {width} = this.props;

  return (
  <Grid
    className={styles.BodyGrid}
    columnCount={1000}
    columnWidth={this._cache.columnWidth}
    deferredMeasurementCache={this._cache}
    height={400}
    overscanColumnCount={0}
    overscanRowCount={2}
    cellRenderer={this._cellRenderer}
    rowCount={50}
    rowHeight={35}
    width={width}
  />
  );
}
```

But neither `Table` nor `Column` has `deferredMeasurementCache` prop. My current code looks like this:

```
return (
    <div>
      <AutoSizer disableHeight>
        {({width}) => (
          <Table
            ref="Table"
            disableHeader={disableHeader}
            headerClassName={styles.headerColumn}
            headerHeight={headerHeight}
            height={height}
            noRowsRenderer={this._noRowsRenderer}
            overscanRowCount={overscanRowCount}
            rowClassName={this._rowClassName}
            rowHeight={useDynamicRowHeight ? this._getRowHeight : rowHeight}
            rowGetter={rowGetter}
            rowCount={rowCount}
            scrollToIndex={scrollToIndex}
            sort={this._sort}
            sortBy={sortBy}
            sortDirection={sortDirection}
            width={width}>
              <Column
                label="Index"
                cellDataGetter={({rowData}) => rowData.index}
                dataKey="index"
                disableSort={!this._isSortEnabled()}
                width={60}
              />
              <Column .../>
          </Table>
        )}
      </Autosizer>
   </div>
);
```

How can I use `Measurer` in Table?

Comment: Shall I think one column as a cell and use `<CellMeasurer>` to wrap around `<Column>`?

Comment: API documentation now provides an example of this: https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/CellMeasurer with source code here: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/CellMeasurer/CellMeasurer.DynamicHeightTableColumn.example.js

Answer (score 8):

The documented API for react-virtualized does not support using `CellMeasurer` in a `Table`.  That leaves a few options within react-virtualized, including:

- implement using `Grid` and external column headings
- implement using `Table` with dependencies on internals not documented in the API

The following outlines a solution to the latter approach that works with react-virtualized v9.21.1 (the latest version as of July, 2019).  Of course such an approach risks that changes to internals in future releases of react-virtualized will break something.

There are several issues to deal with, including:

- `Table` uses a `Grid` internally to provide virtualized scrolling, but doesn't expose it in the API everywhere it is needed.
- The `Grid` only has one column, which contains all of the `Column` cells in a row, but the `Grid` is passed as the parent for rendering `Column` cells.  As a result, one `Grid` cell can be associated with many `Column` cells, a situation that `Grid` and  `CellMeasurer` do not support.
- Use of `CellMeasurer` in a `Grid` depends on the `Grid` directly managing all of the cells in a row, without an intervening `rowRenderer`, while `Table` has its own row rendering logic.

[In the code examples that follow, some data elements and functions are shown with module-level declarations.  In practice they could instead be defined as members of a component which contains the `Table` or in some cases, perhaps passed as props to a component which contains the `Table`.]

The following solution resolves these issues in a general case of:

- static table data
- static row, column, and cell formatting
- the heights of cells within a column are variable across rows
- multiple columns can have such variable-height cells

For that case, two instances of CellMeasurerCache are used.  `cellCache` is for the height of individual `Column` cells. `rowCache` is for the height of rows.

```
const cellCache = new CellMeasurerCache({
  fixedWidth: true,
  defaultHeight: 20, // keep this <= any actual row height
  minHeight: 10,     // keep this <= any actual row height
});

const rowCache = new CellMeasurerCache({
  fixedWidth: true,
  defaultHeight: 37, // tune as estimate for unmeasured rows
  minHeight: 10,     // keep this <= any actual row height
});
```

For the `Table` component:

- add `rowCache` as a `deferredMeasurementCache` prop
- add a `rowRenderer` function
- add a `rowHeight` function

```
  <Table
    ...
    deferredMeasurementCache={rowCache}
    rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
    rowHeight={rowHeight}
  >
```

The functions will be shown later.  `Table` won't do anything with the `deferredMeasurementCache` except pass it along as a prop to the `Table`'s `Grid`.

For every `Column` that needs to be measured, add a `cellRenderer` function.  In many simpler cases, the same function can be used for all measured columns:

```
  <Column
    ...
    cellRenderer={measuredCellRenderer}
  />
```

To help coordinate use of the two caches, three additional data items are needed:

```
const aMeasuredColumnIndex = 2; // any measured column index will do

let rowParent = null; // let a cellRenderer supply a usable value

const cellParent = { // an intermediary between measured row cells
                     //   and their true containing Grid
  invalidateCellSizeAfterRender: ({rowIndex}) => {
    if (rowParent &&
          typeof rowParent.invalidateCellSizeAfterRender == 'function') {
      rowParent.invalidateCellSizeAfterRender({columnIndex: 0, rowIndex});
    }
  },
}
```

`rowParent` is used to expose the Table's Grid to the rowRenderer. `cellParent` serves as an intermediary between the two caches and between a row, its `Column` cells, and the `Table`'s `Grid`.

Next are the three functions that were previously mentioned:

```
function measuredCellRenderer({rowIndex, columnIndex, parent, cellData}) {
  rowParent = parent; // parent is the Table's grid,
                      //   save it for use by rowRenderer
  return (
    <CellMeasurer
      cache={cellCache}
      columnIndex={columnIndex}
      parent={cellParent}
      rowIndex={rowIndex}
    >
      <div>{cellData}</div>
    </CellMeasurer>
  );
  // Note: cellData is wrapped in a <div> to facilitate height
  // styling, for example adding padding to the <div>, because CellMeasurer
  // measures the height of the content box.
}

function rowRenderer(params) {
  return (
    <CellMeasurer
      cache={rowCache}
      columnIndex={0}
      key={params.key}
      parent={rowParent}
      rowIndex={params.rowIndex}
    >
     {Table.defaultProps.rowRenderer(params)}
    </CellMeasurer>
  );
}

function rowHeight({index}) {
  let cellCacheRowHeight = cellCache.rowHeight({index});
  if (cellCache.has(index, aMeasuredColumnIndex)) {
    rowCache.set(index, 0, 20, cellCacheRowHeight);
      // the 20 above is a somewhat arbitrary number for width,
      //   which is not relevant
  }
  return cellCacheRowHeight;
}
```

Note that there are two different uses of `CellMeasurer`.  One is inside the `measuredCellRenderer` function and uses `cellCache` and `cellParent`. The other is inside the `rowRenderer` function and uses `rowCache` and `rowParent`.

Also, the `rowHeight` function doesn't just report a row's height. It is also responsible for transferring the row's `rowHeight` in `cellCache` to the row's cell height for the first and only column in `rowCache`.

This solution can be simplified somewhat when the table has only one measured column.   Only one `CellMeasurerCache` is needed. A single cache can fulfill the
   role of both  `cellCache` and `rowCache`. As a result:

- There is no need for `cellParent`; it can be removed. References to `cellParent` can be replaced by references to `rowParent`, or in the case of the `measuredCellRenderer` function, the `CellMeasurer` `parent` prop can be set directly to the `parent` function argument.
- Inside `measuredCellRenderer`, the `CellMeasurer` needs to be hard-coded for `columnIndex={0}`, even if the measured column is not the first column in the table.
- The `if` statement inside the `rowHeight` function can be removed since there is no need to transfer heights between two cache's.
- The `aMeasuredColumnIndex` can be removed, since it was only referenced in the `rowHeight` `if` statement.